# changing image resolution in Python for a .bmp file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to change the resolution of the .bmp image in python. ( i.e. the pixel/inch information) . Using PIL, for jpg image, for instance, the following code works fine

```
import Image 
im = Image.open("myImg.jpg)
im.save("output.jpg", dpi = (75, 75) )
```

If you view this in some image editing software like GIMP, it shows the Pixel per inch as 75, 75.

But the above code doesn't work when the input image is a .bmp file.

Could someone tell me how to change image resolution for any image  in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that there aren't many programs out there that respect bmp resolution. Windows bitmaps are all 96 dpi.

Also, It looks as though PIL doesn't support a resolution parameter for bitmaps. My `PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py` just writes in $01000000 for the x & y resolution (i'm not sure what that translates to, but I'd guess "96 dpi").

There are [docs](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/decoder.htm) which tell you how to write your own extension .. I'd guess it would be pretty simple to make a copy of the PIL bitmap plugin which accepted resolution as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think input file can be any valid format and output need to be, jpg, pcx, png, tiff, wmf for dpi parameter I think, may be I am wrong, but when I looked at PIL source files, I don't see one for BMP files.